# "expression must have a constant value" visual studio error E0028

Tags: c, visual-c++

```
#define max 40
...

void transpose(int matrix[][max], int* row, int* col)
{
    int data[*row][max]; //expression must have a constant value at *row.
    for (int i = 0; i < *row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < *col; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    int _col = *row; //this *row works fine.
    *row = *col; //also this *row works fine.
    *col = _col;
    for (int i = 0; i < *row; i++) //this *row is fine too.
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < *col; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = data[j][i];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ...
    if (...)
    {
        int row = 0, col = 0;
        int matrix[30][max];
        if (FunctionReadFile(Parameters[0], matrix, &row, &col))
        {
            ...
            transpose(matrix, &row, &col);
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

I tried put 'const' before int but it still show this error at [*row], why does this error occured and how to fix it? Does declaring an dynamic array is the only to fix this problem, any possible solution easier?

Comment: Does your compiler have VLA support?

Comment: There are no VLAs (variable length arrays) in the MNicrosoft's C language implementation. You need to use another compiler or cope without VLAs.

Comment: Stating the obvious, a transposed `[m][n]` matrix has dimensions `[n][m]`, and `data[i][j] = matrix[i][j];` isn't going to do any transposition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your compiler does not support VLA:s, so you should use dynamic allocation:

```
void transpose(int matrix[][max], int* row, int* col)
{
    // Parenthesis matters. This is a pointer to array of size max. Without
    // the parenthesis, it would be an array of pointers to int.
    int (*data)[max] = malloc(max * sizeof (*data)); 

    for (int i = 0; i < *row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < *col; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }

    free(data);
}
```

Do note that I did not check if the allocation failed. You can do that with a simple check. If the pointer is NULL, then the allocation failed. Also, remember to free the memory when you're done with it as shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`_alloca()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/alloca?view=vs-2019) or [`_malloca()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/malloca?view=vs-2019) in MSVC for stack allocation.

> **Return Value**
>
> The `_alloca` routine returns a void pointer to the allocated space,
>   which is guaranteed to be suitably aligned for storage of any type of
>   object. If size is 0, `_alloca` allocates a zero-length item and
>   returns a valid pointer to that item.
>
> A stack overflow exception is generated if the space cannot be
>   allocated. The stack overflow exception is not a C++ exception; it is
>   a structured exception. Instead of using C++ exception handling, you
>   must use Structured Exception Handling (SEH).
>
> **Remarks**
>
> `_alloca` allocates size bytes from the program stack. The allocated
>   space is automatically freed when the calling function exits (not when
>   the allocation merely passes out of scope). Therefore, do not pass the
>   pointer value returned by `_alloca` as an argument to `free`.
>
> There are restrictions to explicitly calling `_alloca` in an exception
>   handler (EH). EH routines that run on x86-class processors operate in
>   their own memory frame: They perform their tasks in memory space that
>   is not based on the current location of the stack pointer of the
>   enclosing function. ...

For example:

```
void transpose(int matrix[][max], int* row, int* col)
{
    int ( *data )[ max ] = _alloca( max * sizeof( *data ) );
    for (int i = 0; i < *row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < *col; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
...
```

Or, with `_malloca()`, which requires you to call `_freea()`:

```
void transpose(int matrix[][max], int* row, int* col)
{
    int ( *data )[ max ] = _malloca( max * sizeof( *data ) );
    for (int i = 0; i < *row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < *col; j++)
        {
            data[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
    ...
    _freea( data );
...
```