# Why I got this (Error (active) E0028 expression must have a constant value - line 23) for Array in C

Tags: arrays, c

/* In the space provided below, write a C code which asks a user how many numbers (up to 100) they want to enter.
The program then stores the data in an array and sends it to a function to compute the average of the numbers of the array.
The function should then return the average and the program should then print the average. */

```
      #include<stdio.h>

    float find_average(int *arr,int size){
       float sum=0; // set sum to 0

       // loop calculates the sum of values in the array
       for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            sum+=arr[i];
       }

       //find average and return
       float average=sum/size;
       return average;
    
    }
    
    int main(){
       int size; // int variable which stores the size of array
       printf("Enter array size (up to 100): \n");
       scanf("%d",&size); // user input of array size
       int array[size]; // array initialization
       printf("Enter the values into array:\n");

       // user input of the array values
       for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
       {
            scanf("%d",&array[i]);
    
       }
       float average=find_average(array,size); // calling find_average function by passing array and it's size
       printf("The average of array values is: %.2f\n",average);
    
    }
```

Why I got this (Error (active) E0028 expression must have a constant value) for Array in C. I'm using visual studio 2019.

Comment: Your C compiler does not support Variable Length Arrays (VLAs)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["expression must have a constant value" visual studio error E0028](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58975523/expression-must-have-a-constant-value-visual-studio-error-e0028)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, you are right, I ran it on an online compiler and everything worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code: the array is given the fixed length of 100 and input given by the user is checked against that value. Note: this would deserve a #define instead of a hard coded constant. Another solution would have been to dynamically allocate the array according to the user input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float find_average(int* arr, int size) {
    float sum = 0; // set sum to 0

    // loop calculates the sum of values in the array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }

    //find average and return
    float average = sum / size;
    return average;
}

int main(void) {
    int size; // int variable which stores the size of array
    printf("Enter array size (up to 100): \n");
    scanf("%d", &size); // user input of array size
    if (size > 100) {
        printf("I told you max 100!");
        return;
    }
    int array[100]; // array storage 
    printf("Enter the values into array:\n");

    // user input of the array values
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    float average = find_average(array, size); // calling find_average function by passing array and it's size
    printf("The average of array values is: %.2f\n", average);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use 100 (the maximum number of items specified) for the array size, and throw an error when the user asks for an array size bigger than that.

```
       int size; // int variable which stores the size of array
       do {
           printf("Enter array size (up to 100): \n");
           scanf("%d",&size); // user input of array size
           if (size >= 100) {
               printf("I told you up to 100, you entered %d\n", size);
           }
       } while (size >= 100);
       int array[100]; // array initialization  (100 elements despite we can use less)
              // ^^^ this expression is what must be constant, not the contents of a variable.
       printf("Enter the values into array:\n");
       // ...
```